# python SSL Connection to Windows Server

Tags: python, powershell, ssl

In my PowerShell script I SSL connect to windows server with the following code:

```
#SSL connecting to server 
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
```

How do I do it with Python script (without request me for a Certificate path)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
import ssl

# SET VARIABLES
packet, reply = "<packet>SOME_DATA</packet>", ""
HOST, PORT = 'XX.XX.XX.XX', 4434

# CREATE SOCKET
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(10)

# WRAP SOCKET
wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA")

# CONNECT AND PRINT REPLY
wrappedSocket.connect((HOST, PORT))
wrappedSocket.send(packet)
print wrappedSocket.recv(1280)

# CLOSE SOCKET CONNECTION
wrappedSocket.close()
```